# Non-ASCII PHP email subjects and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

As I understand it, PHP mail() cannot just accept email subjects with, say, Chinese, characters in them without some further commands.  I'm trying to send emails with Chinese characters in the subject line and seem to be running up against a roadblock.  Does anyone know how I can use CodeIgniter to send these emails? And while I'm at it, I also have to do Korean, Japanese and Russian.  So I need some kind of flexible solution that will handle all non-ASCII characters.  Sounds like a tall order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `mb_encode_mimeheader` function to encode your email subject:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php

More precisely, `mail()` accepts anything but the servers and/or email clients used during the mail transport will certainly not accept anything when conforming to the related RFCs ;-)

Comment: Sounds like it will work, but I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_encode_mimeheader() in /home/configur/public_html/application/controllers/resources/login.php on line 315.  Isn't mb_encode_mimeheader part of native PHP or do I need to call another function first?